# wcf message response parameter

Tags: wcf

I've read this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx about dynamic responses in wcf. 
The sample on the bottom fit my goal pretty well. This is what i did:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/salaries({queryString})")]
    Message GetSalaryByQuery(string queryString);
```

and my GetSalaryByQuery-Method:

```
public Message GetSalaryByQuery(string querystring)
    {
        if (WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Accept == "application/json")
            return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateJsonResponse<Result>(Salary.GetSalaryByQueryJson(querystring));
        else
            return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateAtom10Response(Salary.GetSalaryByQuery(querystring));          
    }
```

It is pretty similiar to the example i found. 
But its not working however. It says that there is another parameter besides the message. I googled  the message-class and it seems to me that its not possible to add an parameter to a message-response.

Is there a way to pass a parameter with the request and get a response with a message object?

Is there another way to get the dynamic response?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I just deleted the Metadata-Enpoint and the behavior. My Webservice provides metadata on its own and therefore doesnt need to have the mex-Metadata defined.